# Regex match a group not ending with specific string

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm using javascript regex engine, and I have difficulties using a regex :

Here is a Sample (it's an ugly js script extraction of what I have to match):

```
{data = function() {[{id:"1441-aeze",name:"theme1"},{id:"1441-aezb",name:"theme2"},{id:"1441-aezc",name:"theme3-a"},{id:"1441-aezd",name:"theme1-mtr"},{id:"1441-aezf",name:"theme4"}]}}
```

My regex try :

```
id:"([^"]+)",name:"(?![^"]*mtr$)[^"]*"
```

Expected result for matching group 1:

```
Match[1] : 1441-aeze
Match[1] : 1441-aezb
Match[1] : 1441-aezc
Match[1] : 1441-aezf
```

But it's matching every portion of my sample. I don't understand why

Here is reg101 : [Regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/tY1aG7/1)

Comment: What do you want to match and what not ?

Comment: I don't know what that `$` is supposed to do, but you should replace it with `"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure, what the `$` in your lookahead is supposed to do, but unescaped it matches at the end of the string (or end of the line with m-Modifier) - but there is no end of a line at the end of your match. In your pattern, the `"` signals the end of the match, so you can just replace the `$` with `"` to get it working, like `id:"([^"]+)",name:"(?![^"]*mtr")[^"]*"`

See your updated link: https://regex101.com/r/tY1aG7/4

Answer (score 1):

here is one way using this pattern

```
id:"([^"]+)",name:"(?:.(?!mtr))*?\}
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tY1aG7/2)

---

here is another

```
id:"([^"]+)",name:"(?:[^m]|m(?!tr))*?\}
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tY1aG7/3)